# How to show form errors in index.html.erb in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

**suppliers_controller.rb**

```
    class SuppliersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_supplier, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /suppliers
  # GET /suppliers.json
  def index
    @suppliers = Supplier.all
  end

  # GET /suppliers/1
  # GET /suppliers/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /suppliers/new
  def new

  end

  # GET /suppliers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /suppliers
  # POST /suppliers.json

  def create
    @supplier = Supplier.new(supplier_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @supplier.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Supplier was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @supplier }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new'}
        format.json { render json: @supplier.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /suppliers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /suppliers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @supplier.update(supplier_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @supplier, notice: 'Supplier was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @supplier.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /suppliers/1
  # DELETE /suppliers/1.json
  def destroy
    @supplier.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to suppliers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_supplier
      @supplier = Supplier.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def supplier_params
      params.require(:supplier).permit(:name, :supplier_type)
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @supplier do |f| %>

  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :name , placeholder:"Name" %>
  <br>

  <%= f.input :supplier_type , placeholder:"Supplier Type", label:"Supplier Type", :collection => ['Agent', 'Farmer'] ,:class => "supp" , :selected => 'Agent'%>
  <br><br>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <%= f.button :submit ,value:"Add" , :class=>"btn btn-primary" , :remote => true  %>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button> 

<% end %> 
</div>
```

**supplier.rb**

```
    class Supplier
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :supplier_type, type: String
  validates_presence_of :name, :supplier_type
  validates_uniqueness_of :name 
end
```

How to display the form errors in index.html.erb.

Note: Suppose i have enter duplicate value in suppliers form then it will respond to new action in controller and says name already taken. This message will be shown in index.html.erb. How's it possible please help me.

Answer (score 0):

@kiran

I see you uses bootstrap. Here some simple helper you can use for your needs:

```
def errors_for(object)
    if object.errors.any?
        content_tag(:div, class: "panel panel-danger") do
            concat(content_tag(:div, class: "panel-heading") do
                concat(content_tag(:h4, class: "panel-title") do
                    concat "#{pluralize(object.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this #{object.class.name.downcase} from being saved:"
                end)
            end)
            concat(content_tag(:div, class: "panel-body") do
                concat(content_tag(:ul) do
                    object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                        concat content_tag(:li, msg)
                    end
                end)
            end)
        end
    end
end
```

Just add code above to application_helper and u can use

```
<%= errors_for(@user) %>
```

snippet. Have a nice stackoverflow :)